# Run Espresso test methods as steps

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I'm writing android instrumentation test using Espresso. It supposed to be an automated test for an existing test case, which consists of several steps. Now my test method looks like the following:

```
class TestCaseName {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val activityTestRule = ...

    @Test
    fun hugeUglyTest() {
      // step 1: ...
      /* performing some actions */

      // step 2: ...
      /* performing some actions */

      // step 3: ...
      /* performing some actions */

      // step 4: ...
      /* performing some actions */

      // step 5: ...
      /* performing some actions */

      // step 5: ...
      /* performing some actions */

      // and so on ....
    }
}
```

And there're two problems:

- It looks ugly
- It's very hard to find a step that caused a failure

I wanted to split that huge test method into separate ones and execute each of them them as a test case step like so:

```
class TestCaseName {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val activityTestRule = ...

    @Test
    fun step_1_name() {
       /* performing some actions */
    }

    @Test
    fun step_2_name() {
       /* performing some actions */
    }
    // and so on
}
```

I've created my own JUnitRunner, which sorts these methods by the step number and retains an instance of the test.

The problem is - I can't make Espresso keep the app alive between the method calls. It always closes launched activity, but I need to keep it opened to pass the next steps from the same point. I've tried to create a custom `ActivityTestRule`, but wansn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I feel your pain and I think you made the right decision by splitting up each step. However the way you want to execute your tests is not exactly possible. In fact, it's against the logic of automated UI testing. **Espresso** framework is meant to simulate one short user interaction and then close the app with a proper result (success or fail). By looking at your example I can suggest you another way to implement your test cases. Although it's possibly code duplication.

```
class TestCaseName {

    @Test
    fun test_action_1() {
       /* perform step 1 */
    }

    @Test
    fun test_action_2() {
       /* perform step 1 */
       /* perform step 2 */
    }

    @Test
    fun test_action_3() {
       /* perform step 1 */
       /* perform step 2 */
       /* perform step 3 */
    }
    // and so on
}
```

If your concern is to follow the steps while tests are running, you can simply use `Thread.sleep(time_in_miliseconds)` between steps. Again, these are not the most elegant solutions but might be useful at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering to that there is no clean way of doing this as it is a very common use case for end to end tests.
It doesnt look like there is a perfect way but using the `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` for your junit test class or using TestNG to declare dependants test steps can create this behaviour.
Maybe using jgiven and implementing the different steps as given steps can also lead to solution but is not so handy.